# Terms for levels of wisdom/ability beyond grasshopper

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Many people are familiar with the term *grasshopper* and with its origins in the 1970s TV show *Kung Fu*. My question is, is this just a one off, or are there any other terms for higher levels of learning/awareness/whatever in the same vein? In other words, *grasshopper* means novice or beginner; are there any similar terms for intermediate, skilled, expert, and/or master?

Sample sentence: "Ah so, grasshopper, you have learned much, and from now on I shall call you [intermediate term] in recognition of your growing abilities."

Comment: Welcome to the site! FWIW, I've never heard of this term.

Comment: I can't recall other names that occurred after that one.

Comment: Many people are NOT familiar with that usage.  Older people will think first of Jiminy Cricket, and younger people will no doubt think of some superhero monster or some such.

Comment: The thing is, "grasshopper" was Master Po's nickname for Kwai Chang Caine.  It was NOT a generic term he used for any and all of his students and it was not a reflection of Caine's skill level.  He continued to call Caine "grasshopper" from Caine's first entry into the monastery until he left to seek his own path.

Comment: If you are familiar with the program, you know  why he was called that. It stemmed from his first meeting with Po, who is blind, but pointed out a grasshopper at Kwai's feet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a false premise.

Comment: Clearly 'Gecko' might be a good one:  https://youtu.be/W2fOXHbraTo?t=36

Comment: "journeyman" is used to refer to people with intermediate skill

Comment: @Phil It's not a false premise. The term *grasshopper*, stemming from the show *Kung Fu*,  ***is*** used to refer to a novice. I'm sure plenty of uses can be found.  The [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Grasshopper&defid=2726777) has this in its top definition, while also containing the much less remembered specific origin of the scene & circumstances in which Cain sees a grasshopper. I'm familiar with the show (own the 3 DVD set), use the term, but don't necessarily recall the scene.

Comment: @Hellion And I thought he called him 'grasshopper' because, being young and half American, he initially lacked the focus and deep concentration essential for meditation, making his progress to enlightenment more difficult. You live and learn!

Comment: A practitioner of kung fu who trains for 17 years, finally achieves the status of master, and then dies within 24 hours is, I believe, termed a _cicada_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a one-off term. There is no commonly-understood successor.